# OSX EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION when call _mm_shuffle_epi32

Tags: xcode, macos, aes

I got an error in runtime "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_i386_INVOP)" after executed next line of code:

```
var1 = _mm_shuffle_epi32(x1,0xFF);
```

On my MacBook Pro mid 2015 code works fine. On Mac mini late 2012 an error occurs.

Both machines have:

- osx 10.13.1
- xcode 9.1
- gcc --version:

  Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
  Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.38)
  Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.2.0
  Thread model: posix

What I'm doing wrong?

You [can try](https://github.com/afrokick/unihive-native-libs) to build it

Answer (score 0):

I see that `var1 = _mm_shuffle_epi32(x1,0xFF)` runs right after `__m128i xout1 = _mm_aeskeygenassist_si128(*xout2, rcon)`--this is an [AES-NI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set) instruction.

If your Mac doesn't support AES-NI, it would trigger the exact crash you're getting (EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION). The late 2012 Mac mini should have an i5-3210M  (Ivy Bridge) which supports AES-NI. Are you sure your Mac mini is late 2012?

Comment: Model Name: Mac mini
  Model Identifier: Macmini6,1
  Processor Name: Intel Core i5
  Processor Speed: 2.5 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores: 2
  L2 Cache (per Core): 256 KB
  L3 Cache: 3 MB - Yes, I'm sure. late 2012